# Subgroup proof verification.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group, K is a fixed positive integer.
$H$={$a\in$ $G$ $|$ $|a|$ divides K} .

Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My way of proving *(Let me know how I could make it better or if something is wrong)*:

Let $e$ be the identity in $G$ .
$e=e^{1}$ so $|e|$ divides K. $e \in H$, So $H$ is not empty.
for $a \in G$, $(a^{-1})^{|a|}=a^{-|a|}=(a^{|a|})^{-1}=e^{-1}=e$.
so $|a^{-1}|=|a| \rightarrow a^{-1}\in H$.
Let $a \in G$ and $b \in G$, such that $ab \neq e$. 
Because $G$ is abelian ,and after associativity :$(ab)^{|a||b|}= (a)^{|a||b|}(b)^{|a||b|}
=(a^{|a|})^{|b|}(b^{|b|})^{|a|}=e^{|b|}e^{|a|}=e
\rightarrow  |ab|$ divides $|a||b|$ because $ab \neq e$ we have:

If $\gcd (|a|,|b|)=1$,and $ab \neq e$, $|ab|=|a||b|$    $\Delta$

Let $a \in H$ and $b \in H$ such that $ab \neq e$. let d=$\gcd(|a|,|b|)$,and $\alpha$  and $\beta$ , such that $|a|=d\alpha$  and $|b|=d\beta$ so $|a^{d}|=\alpha$ and $|b^{d}|= \beta$. we have $\gcd(\alpha ,\beta )=1$.
If $a^{d}b^{d} = $e , then $|ab|$ divides d which divides $|a|$ ,so it divides K  .
Otherwise by using $\Delta$, and after associativity and commutativity in $G$:
$|a^{d}b^{d}|=\alpha\beta \rightarrow  |(ab)^{d}|=\alpha\beta$. Therefore $\require{enclose}\enclose{circle}[mathcolor="red"]{\color{black}{\require{cancel}\xcancel{|ab|=d\alpha\beta=d}{\sf(see\ @ccorn\ below)}}}$ $|ab|$ divides $d\alpha\beta=d\alpha d\beta /d=|a||b|/d = LCM(|a|,|b|)$.
As K is a multiple of $|a|$ and $|b|$, $|ab|$ divides K. $ab \in H$.
$H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: "$|ab| = d\alpha\beta$" need not be true, but you can deduce that "$|ab|$ divides $d\alpha\beta$", and the remaining reasoning still works.

Comment: @ccorn This was crucial ! –

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simplify things a lot by noting that $|a|$ divides $K$ iff $a^K=1$.

Using this, verifying that $H$ is a subgroup is easy.

If you can use homomorphisms, then it is easier because $H=\ker\phi$, where $\phi(x)=x^K$. Since $G$ is Abelian, $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

Comment: The first tip made the exercise almost immediate, Could not see that path since the beginning til the end of my attempts . I would not use homomorphism at this stage,because of the flow of the exercises. Although i is very powerful asset .